# how to set add-on congestion control provider by command prompt in windows 8 or 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, internet-connection, windows-8.1

I am trying to set ctcp as a global congestion provider in Windows 8.1.
please help me to How to set Congestion Provider using command prompt in windows 8 or 8.1?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @FalconMomot I m trying to increase my internet speed. I searched and get this type of tricks > add congestion provider to CTCP using command prompt. do you know How to set this in windows 8 machine. I tried but not get success. it getting me error. do you know how to migrate reserved bandwidth.

Comment: @Abhishek - You cannot increase your internet speed with "magic" commands.  Your internet is a certain speed optimizations like what you are trying to might at provide adjust it a few percentage points.  They are often more trouble then they are worth.